# xamp server showing "object not found" on browser

Tags: php, browser, xampp

I have a code which is written in `php`. When I try to run the code on the browser by giving the below both paths it shows the error. I have created the file under the path **E:\xamp\htdocs\bhargavTest**. But when I try to run the code on browser using paths it shows "**object not found**" as shown below images.In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca9QX.jpg) I gave the path as "**localhost/bhargavTest**" where "**bhargavTest**" is a folder which contains my php files.In this second [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCU29.jpg) I gave a local port address with the folder name. But both shows the error.I tried even giving the full to the "**localhost:82/xamp/htdocs/bhargavTest**".

Please help me in resolving this

Comment: xamp or xampp ? try adding index.php to your url for once

Comment: if `bhargavTest` is a folder, then you should write file name with extension of that folder. Suppose you have `index.php` in `bhargavTest` folder then you can omit the file name, but if you want to execute other than `index.php` file, you have to write the file name with php extension.
try like this: `localhost/bhargavTest/` or `localhost/bhargavTest/filename.php`

Comment: @TarangP the folder is named as xamp. I tried adding the index.php which contains only hello world to print. It shows "not found"

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay i tried the path you have specified it shows "not found"

Comment: Did you start XAMPP apache service?

Comment: Hi @bhargav, you got it fixed?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay i started the xamp server also

Answer (score 0):

Check if in `httpd.conf` file the DocumentRoot param is pointing to the folder htdocs.